# CodeIgniter - Checking to see if a radio button is checked in the database

Tags: codeigniter

Im having a bit of trouble putting some code together ... What im trying to do is add some code to the code i have at the moment to check radiobuttons that are checked in the database.

The code i have at the moment takes all roles from the database, outputs them using a foreach statement, but also splits the results into 2 columns, this is what i have at the moment.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$output = "";
foreach($roles as $row){
    if($i > 0){
        $i = 0;
    }
    if($i == 0) {
        $output .= "<div class='box'>";
    }

    $output .= '<div class="row">';
    $output .= '    <input name="_'.$row->key.'" type="radio" id="'.$row->key.'" class="radio" />';
    $output .= '    <label for="'.$row->key.'" style="text-transform: lowercase;">'.$row->name.'</label>';
    $output .= '</div>';

    if($i ==0) {
        $output .= "</div>";
    }

    $i++;
}
if($i != 1) {
    $output .= "</div>";
}
echo $output;
```

?>

Ok, so what i want to do is check the radio button in the code that i posted, only when there is a match in the database, So to get the values that were checked by the user, i use the following.

Model

```
    function get_roles_by_id($freelancerid)
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$this->table_name.' WHERE user_id = "'.$freelancerid.'"');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Then my controller looks like this

```
$data['positions'] = $this->freelancer_roles->get_roles_by_id($freelancer_id);
```

As that is bring back an array i cant use a foreach statement to check the radio button id's that are returned in the positions array.

Could someone help me to figure this out.

Cheers,

Comment: what $data contain position and roles also right?

Comment: Yes ... the call for the $roles in the controller is $data['roles'] = $this->roles->get_roles();

Comment: Do you mean radio buttons or checkboxes? If it's a radio button you can only have one option selected. Checkboxes can have many things selected. That will determine how you store your selections in the database.

Comment: Yes i mean radio buttons, what happens with the code above is that it loops through a list of roles and adds a radio button to each with different names so that you can select a few of them, then it saves them to the database with the id of the person thats filing out the form, the name of the selected radio button, and the code ... So if a user clicks 4 radio buttons, there will be 4 values saved to the database ... they are then extracted out of the database based on that users id ... so it will return an array of 4 rows

Comment: Offtopic, but you really should use query binding when composing dynamic queries like that: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html (check the bottom of that page)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question and it seems a fairly simple thing you are trying to do. If

You should have your model only return an array of the names of the checkboxes saved by the user in the following format: array("checkbox1", "checkbox2", "checkbox3") then in your output
you can simply use the native php function in_array()

for example:

```
   $output .= '<div class="row">';
   $output .= '    <input name="_'.$row->key.'" type="radio" id="'.$row->key.'" class="radio"';
   if(in_array($row->name, $data['positions']) { $output .= ' checked '; }
   $output . = '/>';
   $output .= '    <label for="'.$row->key.'" style="text-transform: lowercase;">'.$row->name.'</label>';
   $output .= '</div>';
```

As a side note, you have the following code:

```
if($i > 0){
        $i = 0;
    }
    if($i == 0) {
        $output .= "<div class='box'>";
    }
```

If you follow the logic in that code you will see that $i will always equal 0 for the second if statement, making both if statements redundant.